# How to secure Basic Authentication fetch method password from client side?

Tags: reactjs, authentication

In my react fetch method i have called a Basic Authentication API with username and password as below:

```
const username = '*******n';
const password = '***********lhW87A3mds';

componentDidMount () {
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));
let that = this;
fetch(api.example.com , {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      credentials: "same-origin" })
      .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
      .then(function(jsonData) {
        return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
      })
});
}
```

It is working fine and i am getting data also. 
But my question is as far as security concern how can i secure this `username` and `password` to prevent from the hacker; because in the client side this username and password is totally visible for the end user. Review the below image of client side JS data.

[image]

Comment: Token generation should be done from server side. You need to have a token generation API endpoint.

Comment: The API i am using is third party api so how to set token from server side ?

Comment: Write API that will generate same token which you are generating currently JS. That is `'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password)`.

Comment: I can not modify in the API code, so is there any way in the ReactJS for authentication ... ?